# How can I validate user-input in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I'm building a console-based bill reminder app as my first project and i'm having some trouble ensuring that the user will enter the proper data when it comes to `floats`.

Based on the python 2.7 documentation and a few answers here on stackoverflow I've come up with the following solution, that is not working.

```
billAmnt = raw_input('How much is this bill?')
try:
    float(billAmnt)
    return True
except ValueError:
    return False
```

This will either return True or False, I need to ask the user again if it's false or continue to the next section of code if it's true.

If there is a good explanation of this elsewhere and you want to point me in the right direction i'd be fine with that as well.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time when you'd like to repeat something until some condition is satisfied, a `while` loop is probably a good candidate.

```
def get_bill_amount():
    while True: # repeat until you hit a break statement or a return
        billAmnt = raw_input('How much is this bill?')
        try:
            amount =  float(billAmnt)
            return amount # exit the loop. 
        except ValueError:
            pass
            #Since I've gotten to the end of the while block, start again from the top!
```